# Connect to Windows Server from Mac

Tags: macos

I want to add a server in postgrey. This server is a Windows machine. But it is not allowing me to add that server. I think it is not able to access that machine. When I tries to access the webpage hosted on that machine, then too it does not allow me to do so. What can be done to connect to Windows server from a Mac machine??

Comment: What is the error or warning message you get when you tries to add the server?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether Firewall is blocking the external access to the Windows server for the specific port which runs the Postgre server.

You can **telnet** to the relevant port(most probably 5432) to check whether that port is opened to access from your machine.

If there is a firewall running on the Windows server, you should contact the server administrator to modified the rules for allowing the access to the postgre app.

Or may be database user you are using doesn't have permission to access the server from your local machine.